# xlst transformation to display departments of each company node

Tags: xslt

I am beginner for XSLT, currently I am trying to display list of <department> in each <company> node.

Below is my XML

```
<employee_data>
 <employeedetails id="1">
    <company id="1">
        <companyname>AOL</companyname>
        <department>IT</department>
    </company>
    <employeename>Patrick</employeename>
    <employeedesg>Software Engineer</employeedesg>
    <employeesalary>18000</employeesalary>
    <employeedoj>10/03/2015</employeedoj>
 </employeedetails>

 ..... similar sets......
 ..... similar sets......

<employeedetails id="10">
    <company id="1">
        <companyname>AOL</companyname>
        <department>HR</department>
    </company>
    <employeename>Patricia</employeename>
    <employeedesg>HR Assistant</employeedesg>
    <employeesalary>18000</employeesalary>
    <employeedoj>10/03/2015</employeedoj>
 </employeedetails>
</employee_data>
```

I have written the below XSLT to fetch only company names, but I want to display all the departments from the various companies.

XSLT:

```
<xsl:key name="companyname" match="/employee_data/employeedetails/company/companyname" use="."/>

  <xsl:for-each select="/employee_data/employeedetails/company/companyname[generate-id() = generate-id(key('companyname',.)[1])]">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="../@id"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the `department` nodes for a `company` simply use the same key that you have used in the grouping of the companies

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('companyname',.)">
    <xsl:value-of select="../department" />
    <br />
</xsl:for-each>
```

As a side note, you can actually simplify your key. You don't actually need to specify the full path to the `company` element, just the name will do

```
<xsl:key name="companyname" match="company" use="companyname"/>
```

You would only need to consider using a path if there were other `company` elements at a different level in the XML hierarchy that you didn't want included.

Also note I am matching `company` and not `companyname` simply to avoid using the `..` parent axis.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" />

    <xsl:key name="companyname" match="company" use="companyname"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="/employee_data/employeedetails/company[generate-id() = generate-id(key('companyname', companyname)[1])]">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('companyname', companyname)" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="company">
        <xsl:value-of select="department" />
        <br />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: additionally, how to make sure we are not repeating the same departments more than once. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can create a second key on the department, and use muenchian grouping on that in the same way. The key would probably need to include the company name though (if the same department can occur in different companies), so it would look like `<xsl:key name="department" match="company" use="concat(companyname, '|', department')" />`. If you can't figure it out, feel free to ask a whole new question. Thanks!

Comment: Tim: Is it possible to update the code with this question itself ? I am not sure whether I am making sense by creating a new question. Not sure about the stack overflow guidelines. Please help.

Comment: This question has been answered and accepted, so in this situation it is perfectly fine to ask a whole new question. (Indeed it could be considered bad practice to change the original question to add a new requirement that wasn't previously mentioned).You just need to make sure your new question is fully "self-contained"  and has all the information in. i.e. Show the input XML, the output you expect, and any XSLT you have tried. Thanks!

Comment: Well, Thanks again Tim. I will proceed to go for a new one :)

Comment: New question has been posted. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29234007/xslt-to-remove-duplicates-entires)