# How to remove a double appearing sibling node using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I've a xml file containing some product. It's a very big file. Then I make a xslt file to build another leighter xml file.

```
<file path="export/freexml.int/FR/26064804.xml" Product_ID="26064804" Updated="20150827060248" Quality="ICECAT" Supplier_id="11077" Prod_ID="30097568" Catid="2943" On_Market="0" Model_Name="Color Show 110 Urban Coral" Product_View="2819" HighPic="http://images.icecat.biz/img/norm/high/26064804-6070.jpg" HighPicSize="34989" HighPicWidth="400" HighPicHeight="355" Date_Added="20150127000000">
  <M_Prod_ID>0000030097568</M_Prod_ID>
  <M_Prod_ID>0000030097568</M_Prod_ID>
  <EAN_UPCS>
    <EAN_UPC Value="0000030097568" />
  </EAN_UPCS>
</file>
```

Here a sample where M_Prod are in double.
And here my xslt, who catch some case where double appear, but I can't find for the hover case

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output  method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ICECAT-interface">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="files.index"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="files.index">
        <xsl:element name="files">
            <xsl:attribute name="Generated">
                <xsl:value-of select="@Generated"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="file"/>
        </xsl:element>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="file">
        <xsl:element name="file">
            <xsl:attribute name="path">
                <xsl:value-of select="@path"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="Prod_ID">
                <xsl:value-of select="@Prod_ID"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="Supplier_id">
                <xsl:value-of select="@Supplier_id"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="Catid">
                <xsl:value-of select="@Catid"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="Updated">
                <xsl:value-of select="@Updated"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="Quality">
                <xsl:value-of select="@Quality"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="M_Prod_ID"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="M_Prod_ID[not(. = ../@Prod_ID)]">
        <xsl:element name="file">
            <xsl:attribute name="path">
                <xsl:value-of select="../@path"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="Prod_ID">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="Supplier_id">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="@Supplier_id">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@Supplier_id"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../@Supplier_id"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="Catid">
                <xsl:value-of select="../@Catid"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="Updated">
                <xsl:value-of select="../@Updated"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="Quality">
                <xsl:value-of select="../@Quality"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I see too grouping solution, But I can't finalyse correctly xslt file .

### Update 1

[Here my sample](http://xsltransform.net/bnnZVw)

Look there are 3 file nodes generated. I want only the two first node.

### Update 2

I want

```
<files Generated="20150916022750">
   <file path="export/freexml.int/FR/26064804.xml"
         Prod_ID="30097568"
         Supplier_id="11077"
         Catid="2943"
         Updated="20150827060248"
         Quality="ICECAT"/>
   <file path="export/freexml.int/FR/26064804.xml"
         Prod_ID="0000030097568"
         Supplier_id="11077"
         Catid="2943"
         Updated="20150827060248"
         Quality="ICECAT"/></files>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [xslt to remove duplicates entries using Muenchian grouping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29234007/xslt-to-remove-duplicates-entries-using-muenchian-grouping)

Comment: @Abel i didn't meant to fix his code; this grouping technique would suffice to get rid of those duplicates

Comment: The standard method for removing duplicates in XSLT 1.0 is *Muenchian grouping*. Read [the article](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) and consult the many examples here on SO.

Comment: I see this grouping several times But I'm a beginner on XSLT. I never find the good way for my case.

Comment: @michael.hor257k is right, of course (though my premonition in favor of simpler solutions, if possible, let Michael frown;). But perhaps no grouping at all is needed. In the comment below my answer, the OP now states that he wants duplicate results, but duplicates removed... :S. Back to the drawing board: Yannick, please provide **exactly the output you need**, as I am lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question edited, following conclusions from discussion.

> How to remove a double appearing sibling node using XSLT

There are several ways of doing that. First and foremost, you can use Muenchian grouping, but you have said that you find that too complex to grasp just yet. So let's look at an alternative.

One way is to add the following to your current stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="M_Prod_ID[. = preceding-sibling::M_Prod_ID[1]]" />
```

You may need to add a priority to the template, because if your other `M_Prod_ID` is to stay the way it is, they will have the same priority and then the latter will be chosen, or an error will be raised:

```
<xsl:template match="M_Prod_ID[. = preceding-sibling::M_Prod_ID[1]]" priority="10"/>
```

#### Test it

It is often a good idea to see something in action in a minimal context to understand how it works. So, I have taken your input file and ran it against the following simplified stylesheet. [Please click here to see it in action on xsltransform.net](http://xsltransform.net/pPqsHUB).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() |@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="M_Prod_ID[. = preceding-sibling::M_Prod_ID[1]]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which results in the following output (duplicate `M_Prod_ID` removed)

```
<file path="export/freexml.int/FR/26064804.xml" Product_ID="26064804" Updated="20150827060248" Quality="ICECAT" Supplier_id="11077" Prod_ID="30097568" Catid="2943" On_Market="0" Model_Name="Color Show 110 Urban Coral" Product_View="2819" HighPic="http://images.icecat.biz/img/norm/high/26064804-6070.jpg" HighPicSize="34989" HighPicWidth="400" HighPicHeight="355" Date_Added="20150127000000">
  <M_Prod_ID>0000030097568</M_Prod_ID>

  <EAN_UPCS>
    <EAN_UPC Value="0000030097568" />
  </EAN_UPCS>
</file>
```

#### Notes

You are using `<xsl:attribute>` `<xsl:element>` a lot, but you can also use literal result elements and attribute value templates:

```
<file path="{../@path}" Prod_ID="{.}" .....>
    <!-- any child elements go here -->
```

Comment: First test is for case or parent Prod_Id= chils m_Prod_Id. I try '<xsl:template match="M_Prod_ID[not(. = ../@Prod_ID)] | M_Prod_ID[not(. = preceding-sibling::M_Prod_ID[1])]">' But I've always double entries in my new XML..

Comment: @YannickIngenierie, please see my update. I have not changed the solution, merely showed its effect and an online example for you to try.

Comment: Not the best answer, Abel.

Comment: It's closer, but in the end I Want 2 lines '<file Supplier_id="11077" Prod_ID="30097568" Catid="2943" ....>'  and <file Supplier_id="11077" Prod_ID="0000030097568" Catid="2943" ....>

Comment: @michael.hor257k, why, what would you suggest? Keys are better, I wanted to keep it simple and given the requirement, this does what it needs to do, no?

Comment: @YannickIngenierie, sorry, I am totally lost. You said you wanted the double entries to be removed. Now you say you actually want duplicates. I showed you how to remove the dupes. Now you want me to show how to get them back in?

Comment: Sorry. I'm frensh and my english is certainly really rustish.... In my sample it's generate 3 rows '<file Supplier_id="11077" Prod_ID="30097568" Catid="2943" ....>' and <file Supplier_id="11077" Prod_ID="0000030097568" Catid="2943" ....> and this last is twice. cause there are 2 lines '<M_Prod_ID>0000030097568</M_Prod_ID>' This is this third line I don't want.

Comment: @YannickIngenierie Please stop posting snippets of code in comments. Instead, edit you question and provide a representative example, showing the input and the expected output, along with an explanation of the required logic.

Comment: I Update my questions

Comment: @YannickIngenierie That's not what I asked for. Voting to close down as unclear.

Comment: @YannickIngenierie, Here's one of my suggestions applied to your scenario, which results in two `file` elements: http://xsltransform.net/3NJ38Yy.

Comment: @Abel why in the end you're **0000030097568** repeated ?

Comment: Because it's in your data @yannick. You haven't shown what you want, I can only guide you, the rest is then up to you

Comment: I Update question. It's close You says but I don't know why 0000030097568 is just before </files>. Sorry, I'm a beginner. In my first sample it's not there.

Comment: @yannic, there's nothing wrong with being a beginner, the problem here is that it was not clear what you were after. However, the technique I showed in my post is still valid. Here's an update that uses a delete-template to remove the non-matched node: http://xsltransform.net/3NJ38Yy/2

Comment: Ok, It's good. But With your sample, I lost one old case. Look [here](http://xsltransform.net/bnnZVw/9) . in this sample I haven't result with prod_id=DOCUMATE 3640. And that's why I used :  <xsl:template match="M_Prod_ID[not(. = ../@Prod_ID)]">

Comment: @YannickIngenierie, let's not turn this into a discussion thread. That is not what this site is about. It is about Q&A, about questions that can be answered. You can ask a new question if you have another problem. Try to be clear. If English is a problem, show the code, show the input, show the expected output and show your current output. That'll prevent long threads like these.

Comment: @YannickIngenierie, I have updated my question with the results of our conversation. I chose a slightly different solution, more based on the original, but the result is the same. See also my suggestion at the end to make XSLT editing a bit more pleasuring.